# hacer un count con dos tablas

Tags: php, mysqli

ok ya se el tema del while y todo eso se como obtener todo de una tabla,
ahora lo que quiero es lo siguiente: tengo dos tablas una "**amigos**" otra "**principal**" en este caso no quiero imprimir nada, la tabla **amigos** contiene los **id** de los usuarios que son amigos ejemplo "de" y "para" la otra tabla solo contiene un campo id_user sin contar el auto incrementable hay una accion que guarda el id del los usuarios en la tabla "principal" lo que necito es hacer una consulta que me diga cuantos id hay en la tabla "principal" que sean mis amigos ejemplo del codigo para mejor entendimiento

**mi consulta**

```
<?php
    include"conexion.php";
     $yo=$_SESSION["id"];
           //hago una consulta en la tabla amigos donde de sea mi id 
      $ami=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM amigos WHERE de='$yo' ");

      while  ( $obtener_amigos_id=mysqli_fetch_assoc($ami)){
          //aqui saco todos los id que son mis amigos, nose si esta consulta while 
          este correcta a sinceridad
        $id_de_amigos=$obtener_amigos_id["para"];
        }
          //otra consulta en la tabla principal para saver cuantos amigos mios hay aqui
           //tengo 9 amigos y en esta tabla hay 5 amigos mios
        $mostrar_cantidad_amigos= mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM principal 
        WHERE id_user='".$id_de_amigos["para"]."' ");

         $cantida_id_amigos=mysqli_num_rows($mostrar_id_amigos);

       //solo me arroja uno y tengo 9 amigos, de esos 9 el resultado esperado es 5
            echo $cantida_id_amigos;
     ?>
```

agradeceria una ayuda de por que no estoy reciviendo el resultado esperado

Comment: Hola, ¿Qué función tiene el campo "para" de tu tabla principal?

Comment: "de" contiene mi id de session osea usuario que envia la solicitud y "para" contiene el id de el usuario a quien se la envias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes probar con:

```
<?php
include"conexion.php";
    $yo=$_SESSION["id"];

    $sql_1=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM amigos WHERE de='$yo' ");
    //Variable que contará el número de amigos.
    $contadorAmigos = 0;
    while  ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_1)){
        $sql_2 = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM principal WHERE id_user='".$row["para"]."' ");
        //Si se encuentra una ID para ese usuario se suma uno al contador.
        if ($sql_2) {
            $contadorAmigos++;
        }
    }

    echo $contadorAmigos;
?>
```

Lo que no acabo de entender es porque no haces un `COUNT()` desde la consulta SQL para saber el número de amigos que tienes.

`SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_amigos FROM amigos WHERE de=$yo;`

Esta consulta en vez de devolver los registros devolvería algo tipo:

[image: Contador ejemplo]

Y ese número se puede extraer con:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)
$numero = $row['num_amigos'];
```

Comment: entiendo perfectamente a lo que te refieres ya he usado count() en varias ocaciones tambien SUM() pero yo necesito obtener  el id de mis amigos para luego hacer una consulta a la otra tabla para ver cuantos amigos hay conectados sin envargo el codigo que me has propuesto es interesante lo voy a probar ya te cuento que tal me fue damme unos minutos

Comment: ok gracias por tu respuesta pero me esta devolviendo el numero de amigos que tengo en la tabla amigos yo quiero que me devuelva el numero de amigos que hay  en la tabla principal conectados que sean mis amigos  no se si me doy a entender

Comment: gracias amigo , tu codigo me fue util solo hice algunos cambios y obtuve lo que queria solo lo modifique asi:

Answer (score 0):

[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wU88B.png)tu codigo me fue util solo hice algunos cambios y obtuve lo que queria solo lo modifique asi:

```
  <?php
      include"conexion.php";
       $yo=$_SESSION["id"];

        $sql_1=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM main_zone WHERE id_user!='$yo' ");
        //Variable que contará el número de amigos.
        $contadorAmigos = 0;
        while  ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_1)){
            $sql_2 = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM amigos WHERE de ='$yo' AND para='".$row["id_user"]."' ");
            //Si se encuentra una ID para ese usuario se suma uno al contador.
            if ($sql_2) {
                $contadorAmigos++;

            }
        }
        echo $contadorAmigos;
        //obtuve 5 el valor esperado ya que hay 5  conectados en esta tabla
    ?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esta solución es terrible. En el `while` tú estás enviando una y otra vez a consultar a la base de datos... envías la consulta ¿9 veces, 100 veces, 1000 veces, n veces? según los registros encontrados en la 1ª consulta. Aparte de ser algo *extraño* (pues no se entiende por qué la 2ª consulta depende de la 1ª) es poco performante. Con un simple `SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM amigos WHERE ...` obtendrías **con una sola consulta** el total de registros. Por otra parte, el código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de Inyección SQL, deberías usar consultas preparadas para prevenir esos ataques.

Comment: entiendo gracias por la sugerencia nesecito dos consulta por que quiero que mi diga cuantos usuarios hay en la tabla principal que sean mis amigos podrias formular una respuesta con un condigo funcional se lo agradeceria mucho no se mucho sobre performance sorry

Comment: Para una respuesta que resuelva tu problema en cuanto al rendimiento y a la seguridad es necesario entender tu contexto. Propongo que [edites tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/170184/edit) explicando con mayor claridad el contexto: cómo está constituida cada tabla, cómo se relacionan entre sí (mediante qué columnas) y lo que quieres obtener, poniendo ejemplos breves y claros. Sé que parece mucho lo que te pido, pero en este tipo de casos se requiere mucha claridad, de lo contrario será difícil que obtengas una respuesta óptima.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78435/discussion-on-answer-by-andy-hacer-un-count-con-dos-tablas).

Comment: ok vamos a decir que el proyecto es tuyo y tu tienes dos tablas, una que guardara los amigos entre si y otra tabla que guardara el id_de sesscion de cada usuario conectados a una session de la pagina y mediante un boton tu quieres ver cuantos amigos tuyos hay conectados en esa session como lo harias no entiendo como no puedes entender eso tan simple la verdad